# Ghost padding showing up in td, even though I remove padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to make a chessboard by using a table, and thus want to eliminate any padding between the `td` elements:

However, they get a padding of `8px`, and the Developer Tools say that it's inherited from my class `noPadding`:

That doesn't make any sense... How can I fix this?

Rest of the `CSS`, in case it's relevant:

```css
.noPadding {
  padding: 0px;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
  background-image: url(baggrunn.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.thinBorder td,
.thinBorder th,
.thinBorder tr {
  border: solid #000 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.borderless td,
.borderless th,
.borderless tr {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.noBordersBruh table td,
.noBordersBruh th {
  display: block;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top20 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.noPadding {
  padding: 0px;
}

.noMargin {
  margin: 0px;
}

.herregudbredde {
  width: 12.5%;
}

.fullBredde {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table borderless noBordersBruh col-md-12" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="noPadding"><img class="img-responsive fullBredde borderless noBordersBruh" src="Content/ikonene/felt1.png" alt="A8"></td>
      <td class="noPadding"><img class="img-responsive fullBredde borderless noBordersBruh" src="Content/ikonene/felt2.png" alt="B8"></td>
      <td class="noPadding"><img class="img-responsive fullBredde borderless noBordersBruh" src="Content/ikonene/felt1.png" alt="C8"></td>
      <td class="noPadding"><img class="img-responsive fullBredde borderless noBordersBruh" src="Content/ikonene/felt2.png" alt="D8"></td>
      <td class="noPadding"><img class="img-responsive fullBredde borderless noBordersBruh" src="Content/ikonene/felt1.png" alt="E8"></td>
      <td class="noPadding"><img class="img-responsive fullBredde borderless noBordersBruh" src="Content/ikonene/felt2.png" alt="F8"></td>
      <td class="noPadding"><img class="img-responsive fullBredde borderless noBordersBruh" src="Content/ikonene/felt1.png" alt="G8"></td>
      <td class="noPadding"><img class="img-responsive fullBredde borderless noBordersBruh" src="Content/ikonene/felt2.png" alt="H8"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Everything seems correct... Are you sure the problem doesn't come from your picture ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed, it seems so logical, which is why it's so infuriating.. I don't think the issue is anything with the picture, the developer tools say that it's inhereted from the class: 

https://imgur.com/a/Km0ASsn

Comment: Can you try to override the line-height property with a smaller value ? Let me know if it works, it's hard to help you without the code and the images :)

Comment: Similar to what @mdubus said, you're likely to get the answer if you give a better example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . In other words: help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the `.noPadding` class overrides Bootstrap's '.table' class padding, defined for the table element.

I can't test your code but some of these CSS rules should work:

Simple:

```
.noPadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Or, avoiding the `!important` directive:

```
.noPadding,
.table>thead>tr>th.noPadding,
.table>tbody>tr>td.noPadding,
{
    padding: 0;
}
```

You may need to add more selectors to override the `.table` class, as shown in your Imgur screenshot.

Comment: Omg, I can't believe it was so simple as to add '!important', I thought I had tried that earlier too! Totally fixed it. Thx!